# Problem lanching fancybox from within a fancybox on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I'm working with fancybox and I have the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("a#next_fancybox").fancybox();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/sumbit_url",
       data: $("#form").serialize(),
       success: function(msg){ 
           $("a#next_fancybox").trigger('click');
           },
       error: function(msg){
           $('#error').html(msg.responseText);
     });
     return false;
});
</script>
```

Basically there is a form in a fancybox, if the form submits correctly, the user sees a new fancybox. On IE, after the form submits, the fancybox open a new fancybox, but there is no content. It just becomes a tiny white square. Has anyone else experienced this? Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blogged [here](http://zmsmith.com/2010/09/easy-ajax-forms-with-fancybox/) about the solution I developed. Hopefully this helps someone else.